# Node.js Request with Proxies

Tags: node.js, request, httprequest

when attempting to use proxies with the node.js request module I get the following error appear:

```
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http http:80

function doVote(username, captchaKey, proxy, csrf){
    console.log(proxy);
    rp({
        uri: "<url>",
        proxy: "http://" + proxy,
        method: 'POST',
        family: 4,
        form: {
            "username": username
        },
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
        }}).then(body => {
            console.log(body);
            console.log(`Site returned Response Code ${httpResponse.statusCode}`)
            if(body.includes("The CAPTCHA needs to be solved.")){
                console.log("Couldn't send vote!");
            } else {
                console.log("Voted!");
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("===================================");
            console.log(err);
            console.log("===================================");
        });
}
```

I basically wish to send a request with my username to a website.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `url` instead of `uri` ?

Comment: @Ido sadly, same error. Seems to be an alias

Comment: Anything I could potentially try?

Comment: show us the usage of the function, the error message says it's failed to retrieve an ip address from the given domain/host

Comment: Reading further, it seems by doing multiple requests using the request module, that occurs. It’s called by other functions, which get CSRF token etc to do the request.